# Understanding re-renders in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

New to learning class components in React. I have two very simple components, App.tsx and card-list.component.tsx. App.tsx fetches a list of random users (called monsters in the code haha). It also renders a search box and card-list.component.tsx. All it does is provide the ability to filter the list when something is typed in the search bar. Here are the files:

App.tsx:

```
import { ChangeEvent, Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import CardList from "./components/card-list/card-list.component";

export interface Monster {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  address: {
    street: string;
    suite: string;
    city: string;
    zipcode: string;
    geo: {
      lat: string;
      lng: string;
    };
  };
  phone: string;
  website: string;
  company: {
    name: string;
    catchPhrase: string;
    bs: string;
  };
}

interface State {
  monsters: Monster[];
  searchedString: string;
  errorMessage: string;
}

class App extends Component<any, State> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    //console.log("construcor");
    this.state = {
      monsters: [],
      searchedString: "",
      errorMessage: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // console.log("componentDidMount");
    // componentDidMount is called immediately after a React component has been rendered to the screen (mounted).
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((users) => {
        this.setState({ monsters: users });
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the error here
        // console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        // You can update the state with an error message to display it in the UI
        this.setState({
          errorMessage: "Error fetching data. Please try again later.",
        });
      });
  }

  onSearch = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      searchedString: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { monsters: monstersInState, searchedString } = this.state;
    const { onSearch } = this;

    console.log("Logged from App");
    const filteredArray = monstersInState
      ? monstersInState.filter((monster) => {
          return monster.name
            .toLocaleLowerCase()
            .includes(searchedString.toLocaleLowerCase());
        })
      : [];
    // console.log(filteredArray);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          className="search-box"
          type="search"
          placeholder="search monsters"
          onChange={onSearch}
        />
        {this.state.errorMessage ? (
          <h1>Error fetching data</h1>
        ) : (
          <CardList monsters={filteredArray} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

card-list.component.tsx

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { Monster } from "../../App";

class CardList extends Component<{ monsters: Monster[] }> {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.monsters);
    console.log("Logged from CardList");
    const { monsters } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {monsters.map((monster) => {
          return <h1 key={Math.random()}>{monster.name} </h1>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardList;
```

Now I was expecting the console to have the following output:

```
Logged from App               *(When App first renders)*
[]                            *(When App first renders and card-list.component is first called)* 
Logged from CardList          *(When App first renders and card-list.component is first called)* 
Logged from App               *(When componentDidMount is called and the state is updated so it triggers a re-render)*
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] *(When componentDidMount is called and the state is updated so it triggers a re-render)*
Logged from CardList          *(When componentDidMount is called and the state is updated so it triggers a re-render)*
```

But Instead what I see is this in the console. I don't understand why these statements are being logged so many times. Also, what is "installHook.js" and why is it logging stuff to the console?

[image]